# Set Facebook share title and description dynamically using addthis toolbar

Tags: social-networking, addthis

I have been using Addthis toolbar but i need to Set Facebook,linkedIn etc..  share title and description dynamically. Where it is set the my dynamic content("I just signed up for our web site taking place in "). Could you please help me

My Code below

```
  <!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_5"></a>
    <a class="addthis_button_preferred_20"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = { "data_track_addressbar": true };</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-528c7683266cb339"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook and LinkedIn don't work like the other AddThis buttons. Instead of accepting parameters that we pass them, they request the URL you're sharing and gets the data it displays from the meta and link tags in the header. To control how your page is shared on Facebook and LinkedIn you should use OpenGraph tags which are described in Facebook's documentation here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Also, I noticed that you're trying to control the buttons that appear by increasing the preferred number. Are you aware that you can just set a specific service? Details are available here: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/84642-preferred-versus-specified-services

Comment: I have created OG Getting Started FACEbook APP let me know how to integrate my AddThis code, I got API ID